# Insight on an identity of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

There's a formula in *Counting: The art of enumerative combinatorics* by George E. Martin which I don't quite understand.

Let $\Pi(r,n)$ be the number of partitions of $r$ into $n$ parts.
If we want to know the total number of partitions of the $r$ number, $\Pi(r)$, we have to sum such $\Pi(r,n)$ (agreed!)

$$
\Pi(r) = \sum_{j=1}^r \Pi(r,j) \stackrel{?}{=} \Pi(r+r,r),
$$

So, why is the sum $\sum_{j=1}^r \Pi(r,j)$ equal to $\Pi(r+r,r)$? I know that by looking the Pascal's triangle this is always true, but I can't imagine why in principle both problems are the same.

This is exactly the problem of $r$ indistinguishable balls into indistinguishable boxes with no box empty, so I can't find an argument in favor of this equality.

Comment: You used capital $P$ for the unrestricted partitions of $r$, then lowercase $p$ for the partitions with $n$ parts.  What is capital $P$ with two arguments?

Comment: I kept the notation of the book, but it means the same as $p(r,j)$, just with the argument of: the total partition of the $r$ number.

Comment: I found in the [published version of the book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387952253) where this appears, and it uses (Section 19, pg. 34) the Greek letter capital $\Pi$ for both the one argument and two argument functions.  I'll edit the Question and my Answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $\Pi(r,j)$ means the count of partitions of $r$ with exactly $j$ parts, and $\Pi(r)$ means the count of all [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $r$, the equality $\Pi(r) = \Pi(2r,r)$ can be understood with a simple thought experiment.

Consider a partition of $2r$ with exactly $r$ parts.  Now subtract one from each part, which gives a partition of $r$ with at most $r$ parts (since some former parts may have been one and disappeared on subtraction).  But any partition of $r$ will have at most $r$ parts, so this gives a mapping of partitions of $2r$ with exactly $r$ parts to partitions of $r$.

It is easily argued that the mapping is surjective, by giving an inverse mapping.  That is, given a partition of $r$ (with at most $r$ parts), create a partition of $2r$ with exactly $r$ parts by padding the summation with zero summands to get exactly $r$ summands and then adding one to each summand.  Note that this is precisely the reversal of the first mapping.

Finally we want to demonstrate that the first mapping is injective.  Suppose for contradiction that we have initially two partitions of $2r$, each with exactly $r$ parts:

$$ x_1 \le x_2 \le \ldots \le x_r \;,\; \sum x_i = 2r $$
$$ y_1 \le y_2 \le \ldots \le y_r \;,\; \sum y_i = 2r $$

such that the mapping of subtracting one from each part produces the same partition of $r$.  That is, we get the same number of zero summands and the same number of nonzero summands, as indeed $x_i - 1 = y_i - 1$ for all $i$, whether these reduced parts are zeros or not.  Then $x_i = y_i$ all along, and the original partitions of $2r$ were identical.  Ergo the mapping is injective.

Therefore $\Pi(r) = \Pi(2r,r)$.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that this argument can be expressed very nicely in terms of Ferrers diagrams: the bijection between Ferrers diagrams of partitions of $2r$ into $r$ parts and Ferrers diagrams of partitions of $r$ is just removing the first column of the diagram. Its inverse is adding a column of height $r$ to the left of a Ferrers diagram for a partition of $r$.

Comment: These nice visual representations of partitions are [briefly mention in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Representations_of_partitions).  At a glance this topic (Ferrers diagrams) seems to be a surprising omission in the cited book by George E. Martin

Comment: Is there any chance that he has them under the name *Young tableaux*?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I tried Google Book Search-Inside with separate terms "Ferrers", "diagram", "Young", and "tableaux".  Only "diagrams" had any hits, and these were not that kind of diagram (rather graphs and permutation kinds of things).  Of course it's quite possible Google Book search isn't up to the task.

Comment: That does seem odd; I find them very helpful, and I’m not even visually oriented!